# Why does int.__eq__ seem to be not implemented in python2

Tags: python, python-2.7, comparison-operators, magic-methods

I've got a head scratchier and it seems I'm not the only one, but is there really no solution?  I find that hard to believe!

So the question is why can't I call `int.__eq__` with 2 operators or `i.__eq__` with one?  How can I use `__eq__` (and the other comparison operators) for a per item comparison for a sequence of ints?

Here's a dump from python2.7.17:

```
>>> i = 0
>>> type(i)
<type 'int'>
>>> i.__eq__(0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__eq__'
>>> type(i).__eq__(i, 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: expected 1 arguments, got 2
>>> type(i).__eq__(0)
NotImplemented
```

But my dumo from python3.6.9 behaves itself:

```
>>> i = 0
>>> type(i)
<class 'int'>
>>> i.__eq__(0)
True
>>> type(i).__eq__(i, 0)
True
>>> type(i).__eq__(0)  # this is not expected to work, but just for the sake of voodoo.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: expected 1 arguments, got 0
```

I know python2 is no longer supported but there are a few applications that only use python2 and I would like to make my code backwards compatible anyway.

So anyone out there have a solutuon for hacking the comparison magic operator methods as function calls in python2?  I am sure there must be some work around.

It seems there is some information on this. I just read that python2 falls back to using cmp in some cases, while in python3 there is no cmp (or so I read). So I guess the thing to do is not use eq and ne but instead use cmp but I love some additional perspective on this

Comment: Note that `int.__eq__` is actually a bound method (actually, a `method-wrapper`) produced by passing `int` to `type.__eq__`, rather than the unbound `__eq__` defined by `int` (as it is in Python 3). `int.__eq__(int) == True`, `int.__eq__(float) == False`, `int.__eq__(3)` returns `NotImplemented` because you can't compare types and `int` values.

Comment: (You get some hint of this by comparing the return value of `type.__eq__.__get__(int, type)` to `int.__eq__`. I'm not entirely sure `int.__eq__` actually causes `type.__eq__.__get__` to be called, but the both appear to be accessing or creating the same instance of `method-wrapper`.)

Comment: Well I clicked answer my own question but it wouldn't let me and closed my question.  Not sure why when I didn't get to post my answer.  So I will put it here.

Comment: So I found an an answer.  Yes indeed it seems python2 has it reasons for diverting functionality from the magic comparison operators.  Instead it uses __cmp__ or cmp.  So the solution is rather simple and not that in elegant.

Comment: SPECIAL_OPNAMES = \
        { '__eq__': (lambda *args, **kwargs: not cmp(*args, **kwargs)) \
        , '__ne__': (lambda *args, **kwargs: cmp(*args, **kwargs)) \
        } if sys.version_info.major == 2 else \
        {}

Comment: item = 1
    opname = '__eq__'
    t = type(item)
    op = SPECIAL_OPNAMES[opname] if opname in SPECIAL_OPNAMES else getattr(t, opname)
    op(item, 1)  # result is True

Comment: Voted to reopen; the duplicated question explains how `==` works, but doesn't answer why `int.__eq__` didn't seem to work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

The general rule is: don't touch dunderscore methods, use functions and operators instead and those will delegate to dunderscore implementation *as necessary*. In your case you're looking for the `==` *operator* or the functional equivalent `operator.eq`.

```
from operator import eq
from functools import partial

print eq(1, 2)

f = partial(eq, 1)
print f(2)
```